# $\sigma$-field as the smallest $\sigma$-field containing something. Exercise about showing that it is generated by specific sets

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

> Let $\mathcal{B}_i$ be the $\sigma$-fields of subsets of $\Omega$ for $i=1,2$. 
>  Show that the $\sigma$-field $\mathcal{B}_1\vee\mathcal{B}_2$ defined to be the smallest $\sigma$-field containing both $\mathcal{B}_1$ and $\mathcal{B}_2$ is generated by sets of the form $B_1\cap B_2$, with $B_i\in\mathcal{B}_i$ for $i=1,2$.

I think I should rely on the definition below:

> Let $X:(\Omega,\mathcal{A}) \to (R,\mathcal{B})$ be measurable.
> $$\sigma(X)=[A\subset\Omega: X^{-1}(B)=A, \text{for some } B\in \mathcal{B}]$$

---

1. First, the smallest $\sigma$-field $\mathcal{B}_1\vee\mathcal{B}_2$ containing both $\mathcal{B}_1$ and $\mathcal{B}_2$ is the intersection of all the $\sigma$-fields containing both $\mathcal{B}_1$ and $\mathcal{B}_2$, isn't it?
2. How can I rigorously show that the $\sigma$-field $\mathcal{B}_1\vee\mathcal{B}_2$ is $\color{red}{\text{ generated by }}$ sets of the form $B_1\cap B_2$, with $B_i\in\mathcal{B}_i$ for $i=1,2$? 
   In proving this, which is the role of knowing that "$\mathcal{B}_1\vee\mathcal{B}_2$ is the smallest $\sigma$-field containing both $\mathcal{B}_1$ and $\mathcal{B}_2$"?

---

---

Could you please detail your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote by $\mathcal{A}$ the $\sigma$-algebra generated by sets of the form $B_1 \cap B_2$, $B_i \in \mathcal{B}_i$. Equivalently, $\mathcal{A}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all sets of the form $B_1 \cap B_2$ with $B_i \in \mathcal{B}_i$.

> $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{B}_1 \vee \mathcal{B}_2$

Since $\mathcal{B}_1 \vee \mathcal{B}_2$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{B}_1$ and $\mathcal{B}_2$, we have, in particular, $$\mathcal{B}_1 \subseteq \mathcal{B}_1 \vee \mathcal{B}_2 \quad \text{and}\quad \mathcal{B}_2 \subseteq \mathcal{B}_1 \vee \mathcal{B}_2. \tag{1}$$ Now take any $B_1 \in \mathcal{B}_1$ and $B_2 \in \mathcal{B}_2$. Then it follows from $(1)$ that $B_1 \in \mathcal{B}_1 \vee \mathcal{B}_2$ and $B_2 \in \mathcal{B}_1 \vee \mathcal{B}_2$. Since $\mathcal{B}_1 \vee \mathcal{B}_2$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, hence stable under intersections, it follows that

$$B_1 \cap B_2 \in \mathcal{B}_1 \vee \mathcal{B}_2.$$

Consequently, $\mathcal{B}_1 \vee \mathcal{B}_2$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containg all sets of the form $B_1 \cap B_2$ with $B_i \in \mathcal{B}_i$. Since $\mathcal{A}$ is, by definition, the **smallest** $\sigma$-algebra with this property, we conclude that $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{B}_1 \vee \mathcal{B}_2$.

> $\mathcal{B}_1 \vee \mathcal{B}_2 \subseteq \mathcal{A}$

Clearly, $B_2 := \Omega \in \mathcal{B}_2$. Therefore, we see from

$$B_1 = B_1 \cap \Omega$$

that $B_1 \in \mathcal{A}$ for any $B_1 \in \mathcal{B}_1$. Analogously, $B_2 \in \mathcal{A}$ for any $B_2 \in \mathcal{B}_2$. This shows that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra which contains both $\mathcal{B}_1$ and $\mathcal{B}_2$. By definition, $\mathcal{B}_1 \vee \mathcal{B}_2$ is the **smallest** $\sigma$-algebra which this property, and so $\mathcal{B}_1 \vee \mathcal{B}_2 \subseteq \mathcal{A}$.

Comment: Perfect. So, you call $\mathcal{A}$ the $\sigma$-algebra generated by sets of the form $B_1\cap B_2, B_i\in\mathcal{B}_i$. In the first part, you show that $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{B}_1 \vee \mathcal{B}_2$, while in the second part you show that $\mathcal{B}_1 \vee \mathcal{B}_2 \subseteq \mathcal{A}$, which finally means that $\mathcal{B}_1 \vee \mathcal{B}_2 =\mathcal{A}$, right? **[continue]**

Comment: **[continue]** I have just an observation/question about second part, when you show $$\mathcal{B}_1 \vee \mathcal{B}_2 \subseteq \mathcal{A}$$ Why did you write all those passages (cfr. *"Clearly, $B_2 := \Omega \in \mathcal{B}_2$ [...]"*) to show that $\mathcal{A} $  is a $\sigma$-algebra which contains both $\mathcal{B}_1$ and $\mathcal{B}_2$? Isn't that true by initial definition of $\mathcal{A}$? (namely, *"Denote by $\mathcal{A}$ the $\sigma$-algebra generated by sets of the form $B_1\cap B_2, B_i\in\mathcal{B}_i$"*).  $$$$ Thank you a lot!

Comment: @Strictly_increasing Re your first comment: Yes, exactly. Re your 2nd comment: Well, you were asking for a detailed answer and I complied. To conclude from the initial definition of $\mathcal{A}$ that $\mathcal{A}$ contains both $\mathcal{B}_1$ and $\mathcal{B}_2$ it is necessary to note that $\Omega \in \mathcal{B}_1$ and $\Omega \in \mathcal{B}_2$ (without this property, we couldn't conclude the proof). That's about it. Of course, it's possible to write all of this much shorter...

Comment: Pardon, I am sure it is a very trivial fact, but at the moment I cannot get why it is necessary to note that $\Omega \in \mathcal{B}_1$ and $\Omega \in \mathcal{B}_2$ to conclude that $\mathcal{A}$ contains both $\mathcal{B}_1$ and $\mathcal{B}_2$

Comment: @Strictly_increasing Just tell me how you would prove this without using this fact. How do you see from $B_1 \cap B_2 \in \mathcal{A}$ that $B_1 \in \mathcal{A}$? (as usual, $B_i \in \mathcal{B}_i$)

Comment: Yeah, of course..sorry, since $B_1 \in \mathcal{A}\implies B_1 \cap B_2 \in \mathcal{A}$, but not viceversa. So, to show that $B_1 \in \mathcal{A}$ you define $B_1$ as the intersection between itself and $\Omega$, where $\Omega=B_2\in\mathcal{B}_2$. Hence,$$B_1=B_1\cap \Omega \text{ (with } \Omega= B_2) \in \mathcal{A}, \text{ for every }B_1\in\mathcal{B}_1$$
since $\mathcal{A}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by sets of the form $B_1\cap B_2, B_i\in\mathcal{B}_i$. The same rationale applies so as to show that $B_2\in\mathcal{A}$. Got it now, thanks

Comment: Yeah, of course..sorry, since $B_1 \in \mathcal{A}\implies B_1 \cap B_2 \in \mathcal{A}$, but not viceversa. So, to show that $B_1 \in \mathcal{A}$ you define $B_1$ as the intersection between itself and $\Omega$ , where $\Omega=B_2\in\mathcal{B}_2$. Hence, $$B_1=B_1\cap \Omega \text{ (with } \Omega= B_2\in\mathcal{B}_2) \in \mathcal{A}, \text{ for every }B_1\in\mathcal{B}_1$$
since $\mathcal{A}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by sets of the form $B_1\cap B_2, B_i\in\mathcal{B}_i$. The same rationale applies so as to show that $B_2\in\mathcal{A}$. Got it now, thanks

Answer (score 4):

**Hints**: Let $\mathcal C$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $B_1\cap B_2$ where $B_i$ runs over elements of $\mathcal B_i$.

1. Show that both $\mathcal B_i$ are contained in $\mathcal C$.
2. Whenever both $\mathcal B_i$ are contained in a $\sigma$-field $\mathcal D$ of subsets of $\Omega$, then $\mathcal C\subseteq \mathcal D$.

Comment: The part I cannot really understand is.."how to prove that a $\sigma$-field **is generated by something**"? What does this mean? As to your first hint, showing that $\mathcal{B}_1\subset\mathcal{C}$ means showing that "if you are in $\mathcal{B}_1$ you are for sure in $\mathcal{C}$". However, in my mind it would be more intuitive that $\mathcal{C}\subset\mathcal{B}_1$, that is that $\mathcal{C}$ is a subset of $\mathcal{B}_1$ (and of $\mathcal{B}_2$ as well). Sorry, I think I am confused a lot. Thanks for your help @Berci

Comment: It means (by definition) that $\mathcal C$ is the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras that contain the given elements. Don't mix up elements of $\mathcal B_i$ (which are subsets of $\Omega$) with $\mathcal B_i$. Further hint for 1. is that it's very easy, and use that $\Omega\in\mathcal B_i$.

Comment: Point **1.** would allow to show that, since both $\mathcal{B}_1$ and $\mathcal{B}_2$ are contained in $\mathcal{C}$, then $\mathcal{B}_1\cap\mathcal{B}_2\in\mathcal{C}$ Point **2.** would allow to show that $\mathcal{C}$ is exactly the smallest $\sigma$-field containing both $\mathcal{B}_1$ and $\mathcal{B}_2$. Right? $$$$ Anyway, as to point **2.** how can I show that $\mathcal{C}\subseteq\mathcal{D}$ for *every* possible $\mathcal{D}$ containing both $\mathcal{B}_1$ and $\mathcal{B}_2$?